# Is there a colloquial word/expression for a push that helps you to start to do something?

Tags: phrase-requests, slang, translation

To specify my request, I should say that I mean something I can use in a normal conversation, but not in the academic field.

There's such an expression in the Russian language, which sounds like "*volshebniy pendel"*. *volshebniy* means 'magic,' and *pendel* means 'a kick in the ass.' So, it's for situations when you are procrastinating and really need this kick/push/nudge to start doing something.

This might be anything: a line in the book, a phrase in the tv show, a call from your friend, a boss's text, and so on.

Is there any similar expression in English?

Answer (score 18):

[**Light a fire under**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light-a-fire-under) someone (per Cambridge):

> **light a fire under someone**
>
> idiom
>
> *mainly US*
>
> to make someone act quickly or forcefully, especially someone who has not been doing enough before

Comment: Colloquially... You're generally lighting the fire under their arse specifically

Answer (score 16):

**Wake-up call**: This implies that the person is taking things too easily and needs to wake up and get moving. It is less offensive than mentions of kicking someone's rear but still implies an urgent prompt to get going.

**Kick in the pants**: This is slightly more polite than "kick in the ass"

**Kick up the backside**: This AFAIK is only used in British English. It is more polite than "kick up the arse" (also British English). In general the word "arse" in BrE, although meaning the same thing, is used less and considered much more coarse than the US "ass".

> **wake-up call** A portentous event, report, or situation that brings an
> issue to immediate attention. For example, The rise in unemployment
> has given a wake-up call to state governments, or The success of the
> online subscription is a wake-up call to publishers. This metaphoric
> term originated in the second half of the 1900s for a telephone call
> arranged in advance to awaken a sleeper, especially in a hotel. Its
> figurative use dates from about 1990.
> https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wake-up+call

Answer (score 15):

“Kick in the ass” is actually a phrase that I might use (native speaker of Canadian English). Sorry, I haven’t found any references (yet).

but I might use it as follows “my boss gave me a kick in the ass that got me started on the project that I was procrastinating about, and it turned out to be easier than I thought“.

Or “getting out of breath when I ran up the stairs was a kick in the ass that got me serious about exercising”

However, a “kick in the ass” can be both positive and negative, as so many things are in English. Most of the definitions that I have found emphasize the negative aspects, like “my boss threatened to fire me, which was a kick in the ass“. But that in itself might inspire you to start working harder. Tough love.

Also not to be confused with “kick ass“ or “kick butt”.

—-

Less colloquially, you already mentioned “push”. E.g. “my wife pushed me to start the project of cleaning out the garage”..

More: “trigger”, “prompt”.

“nagged” as you “my wife magged me until I started working on the project”

—-

IMHO terms like “boost” are not necessarily a thing that start you on a project, although they might help you along the way.

—-

More figurative:

“Pushed me off the cliff” or “pushed me into the water”

E.g. “my friend pushed me off the cliff into the ocean, where it was sink or swim. Fortunately I swam… and that’s how I got started on my career.”

—-

Riffing off one of the other answers “I lit a fire under his ass, and he finally started working on the project”.

Comment: You might like to add [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kick+up+the+arse) to your resources. Aside: in UK an *ass* is a donkey or a fool.

Comment: "A kick" may be used even if it is not directed to someone's posterior.

Comment: I've also heard the term "Kick in the pants". As in "I didn't like what she said, but it gave me the kick in the pants I needed to get started"

Answer (score 12):

> So, it's for situations when you are procrastinating and really need this kick/push/**nudge** to start doing something.

Why don't you just use **nudge**, just as Richard H. Thaler, and Cass R. Sunstein did in their book [*Nudge*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/014311526X)?

It can be either a noun (as you've used) or a verb, as defined in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nudge) as follows:

> 2 :to prod lightly: urge into action
> … have been *nudged* into starting their own ventures …
> —Janet Bamford

Comment: Or **prod** itself.

Comment: @gidds Actually, "prod" might be closer to what OP's looking for. :)

Answer (score 9):

Another good word: [***impetus***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impetus)

> *1a(1) : a driving force : impulse*
>
> *1a(2): incentive, stimulus*
>
> *1b: stimulation or encouragement resulting in increased activity*

Answer (score 7):

We sometimes speak of **jump starting** something, or of giving something a **jump start**. The idiom originally refers to a car being started with the aid of a battery from another car, but it can be used metaphorically in other contexts. The expression suggests that something can be kept going once it is started, but that assistance is needed to start it.

Comment: Also "kick start," no doubt from motorcycle riding

Answer (score 4):

One colloquial expression used is (from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shot+in+the+arm))

> **a shot in the arm**
> *Fig.* a boost or act of encouragement.
> *The pep talk was a real shot in the arm for all the guys.*
> *The good test grade was a shot in the arm for Gary.*

The literal meaning is an injection of drugs.

Answer (score 3):

If a verb is okay, you can use "to spark" for this. According to [Oxford Learners,](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spark_1)

> to cause something to start or develop, especially suddenly
>
> *The proposal would spark a storm of protest around the country.*

Comment: spark is a good one, and is more like inspire, although in my case it's a bit rude: you kick the person, and they start at last doing something

Answer (score 2):

[Give a hand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-a-hand), [a boost](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/give-somebody-a-boost-up), [a leg up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/give-someone-a-leg-up) 
are expressions that may convey the idea of helping someone to start doing something.

Comment: I don't often comment on other answers, but aren't these expressions used when someone is already active, but can't easily manage?

Answer (score 1):

A word you could use is [initiative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/initiative)

> a new plan or process to achieve something or solve a problem
>
> an introductory step - [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initiative)
>
> an introductory act or step; leading action,   serving to set in
> motion or initiate; introductory; beginning - [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/initiative)

"You need to take the initiative; start your own company before someone else does"

Comment: thank you,  I'm looking for something as "naughty" and informal as mine.

Answer (score 1):

**get-up-and-go**

> My *get-up-and-go* has got up and went.
>
> I lost my [get-up-and-go](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-up-and-go) and my [mojo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mojo).

Links to Cambridge definitions above.